# Record screen and upload on youtube

Tags: video, screenshot, youtube, upload

I'd like to record my screen and have the recorded video automatically uploaded on youtube.

Is there any software that does this?

I know there are screen recorders like Kazam that easily permit to record the screen but they do not automatically upload the video.

Some time ago I tried to create a batch script that took a screenshot every 1 second (1 frame per second is enough for my needs here) but I'm no Linux programmer so I found it very difficult to do (if you can and want to contact me, please do).

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Are you trying to create the video and then, at the end, upload it? Or trying to live stream your screen?

Comment: I'd like to stream, in this way one step (the upload) is automatically done. I could record the stream (Kazam/SimpleScreenRecorder/etc) and then upload it, but if I can get rid of one step the process if more efficient (regarding the time spent on the upload part).

Comment: This might help then: https://linuxforever.info/2017/05/06/how-to-live-stream-to-youtube-from-linux-mint-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OBS Studio. Very well done software for recording the screen and uploading on the web.
You can choose if you want only record, or record locally and upload directly on the web.

OBS: Open Broadcaster Software (OBS Studio): https://obsproject.com

Comment: OBS è perfetto, grazie mille!

Comment: Are you affiliated with OBS? (someone flagged this as "spam")

Comment: @Kusalananda no, there is no affiliation here, but the question was posted on other platforms as well

Comment: @Nicola That question in my comment was meant for Salvatore.

Answer (score 1):

For the screen recording I would suggest [SimpleScreenRecorder](https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr). It may even be available as a package for your distro.

As for the automation part: if you want to automatically upload on Youtube you could have a script watching for new files using for example [inotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). That shouldn't be too difficult and you will find plenty of examples online. If you are really stuck you can open a new question.